# Cross browser paste capture - Mac Opera issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, opera, copy-paste

I'm working on a cross browser paste capture. I've got this working & tested in Chrome and Firefox (on a mac). It *should* work on Chrome and Firefox on a PC as well but I have not had a chance to test it yet. Hopefully I'm not reinventing the wheel, I've looked for a good bit for a jQuery plugin or any javascript really that implements document-wide pasting.

This is **not** yet working in Opera (version 11.52) (on a mac, haven't tested on a PC). My issue is that when the cmd key is pressed, when I press the v key I do not get a `keydown` event. I'm not sure how to fix the issue as I'm not very framilar with Opera.

Work-in-progress jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JgU37/8/).

The javascript below will not work as is, please see the jsfiddle for a working script. To make the script below work you need [this](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2009/07/16/jquery-browser-and-os-detection-plugin/) os detection plugin.

*Question to answer* - How do I make this work in Opera?

*Comments to leave if you like* - Does this work for you? (post browser, os versions in comment)

**update** - Based on the comment Baez left this is a Opera on mac only issue.

**update2** - I've updated the jsfiddle, its simplified the code a bit but still can't get it to work in mac Opera.

---

**javascript (jquery)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Fake paste
    var doFakePaste = false;
    $(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
        $('#status').html('');
        if (($.client.os === "Mac" && e.which == 86 && e.metaKey) ||
            ($.client.os !== "Mac" && e.which == 86 && e.ctrlKey)) {
            doFakePaste = false;
            $('#paste').blur().remove();
        }
    }).on('keydown', function(e) {
        $('#status').html('which: ' + e.which);
        if (($.client.os === "Mac" && e.which == 86 && e.metaKey) ||
            ($.client.os !== "Mac" && e.which == 86 && e.ctrlKey)) {
            doFakePaste = true;
            // got a paste
            $('<div></div>').attr('contenteditable', '').attr('id', 'paste').appendTo('body').on('paste', function(e) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    doFakePaste = false;
                    var html = $('#paste').html();
                    var text = $('#paste').text();
                    $('#resultA').text(html);
                    $('#resultB').text(text);
                    $('#paste').blur().remove();
                }, 1);
            }).focus();
        }
    });

    $('#data').html('os: ' + $.client.os + ' browser: ' + $.client.browser);
});
```

**html** - Again see the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JgU37/8/) for a working copy

```
<p>Click in this window and do a paste (ctrl-v or cmd-v). The pasted text will show up in the boxes below. I hope... the left box will be the HTML and the right box will be the TEXT.</p>

<div id="status"></div>
<div id="data"></div>

<div id="resultA"></div>
<div id="resultB"></div>
```

Comment: Works for me in Windows 7 - Opera 11.60

Answer (score 0):

Not full answer, but part of my experience:

1. You can remove `$.client.os` and use `e.which == 86 && (e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey)`
2. You binded event on `document`. Bind event on `div[contenteditable="true"]` - may be it helps
3. Your code: `attr('contenteditable', '')`. `contenteditable` can be `true`, `false` and `inherit` ( = get value from parent )

Comment: Can't we use just this and not browser detection.                     if (e.type =='keydown' && e.which == 86 && (e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey))